# RSolve does not work as expected

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic, recursion, difference-equations

Why am I getting error

> The arguments should be ordered consistently

for the following code:

```
RSolve[{p[n, m] == m/n p[n - 1, m - 1] + (n - m - 1)/n p[n - 1, m], 
  p[n, n - 1] == 1/n, p[n, 1] == 1/2}, p[n, m], {n, m}]
```

I determined that it complains about my boundary condition `p[n, n - 1] == 1/n`
which does not make sense, since it is a valid boundary condition. It is not possible to express this using `m` in the second argument.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 4):

The solution to this difference equation system is simply `p[n_, m_] -> 1/(m + 1)`, as can be proven by substituting this result into the system.

```
Simplify[{p[n, m] == ((-1 - m + n) p[-1 + n, m])/n + (m p[n, -1 + m])/n, 
    p[n, n - 1] == 1/n, p[n, 1] == 1/2} /. p[n_, m_] -> 1/(m + 1)]
(* {True, True, True} *)
```

Deriving this solution does not seem so simple, however.  The OP observed in the question that `RSolve` throws an error message when given the difference equation system, apparently because it cannot interpret the boundary condition, `p[n, n - 1] == 1/n`.  This expression is readily converted to the equivalent, `p[m + 1, m] == 1/(m + 1)` but to no avail.  Instead, shift the index `n` by `1 - m` to convert the system to the equivalent

```
RSolve[{p[n, m] == m/n p[n, m - 1] + (n - m - 1)/n p[n - 1, m], 
    p[2, m] == 1/(m + 1), p[n, 1] == 1/2}, p[n, m], {n, m}]
```

With this change `RSolve` on longer throws an error, but instead returns unevaluated.  Strangely, `RecurrenceTable` also returns unevaluated.  It is, however, possible to produce a do-it-yourself recurrence table:

```
p[n_, 1] := 1/2
p[2, m_] := 1/(1 + m)
p[n_, m_] := ((-1 - m + n) p[-1 + n, m])/n + (m p[n, -1 + m])/n
Table[p[n, m], {n, 2, 8}, {m, 1, 8}] // TableForm
```

[image]

consistent with the symbolic result.  (In fact, I guessed the symbolic solution from the table above.)  The original formulation of the recurrence equation system can be evaluated in a similar manner.

```
p[n_, 1] := 1/2
p[n_, m_] := 1/n /; n == m + 1
p[n_, m_] := m/n p[n - 1, m - 1] + (n - m - 1)/n p[n - 1, m]
PadRight[#, 7] & /@ Table[p[n, m], {m, 1, 8}, {n, m + 1, 9}] // Transpose // TableForm
```

[image]

as expected.  The actual question is, in effect, why does `RSolve` not behave as one might like.  Who knows?